# pass RDD as parameter and return dataframe to a function - scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create function which takes string or RDD as an argument but returns dataframe.

Code:

```
def udf1 (input: String) = {
  val file = sc.textFile(input);
  file.map(p => Person(
    (p.substring(1, 15)),
     p.substring(16, 20))).toDF()  
}

def main() { 
  case class Person(id: String, name: String)     
  val df1 = udf1 ("hdfs:\\")
}
```

but it retuns always rdd. any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure exactly why your code isn't working, but good `Scala` form would include specifying return types:

```
scala> case class Person(id: Int)
defined class Person

scala> def udf1(fName: String): DataFrame = {
     | val file = sc.textFile(fName)
     | file.map(p => Person(p.toInt)).toDF()
     | }
udf1: (fName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> val df = udf1("file.txt")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int]
```

Comment: May be i was not defining the return type. it works if i define the return the DataFrame works.Thanks!